# Filter List based on the User

Tags: list, permissions

My WSS application's users are either employees of CLIENT-A, CLIENT-B, or CLIENT-C.  Each client has the same type of data and documents.

Users belonging to CLIENT-A can only see CLIENT-A data & docs

Users belonging to CLIENT-B can only see CLIENT-B data & docs

and so on...

I can't see how to only show CLIENT-B's data and documents to CLIENT-B users.

In Asp.Net I could :

```
void Page_Load(...) {
DataTable clientDocs = GetClientDocs(profile.ClientID);
DocumentList.DataSource = clientDocs;
DocumentList.DataBind();
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

to be able to answer your question; is this a permissions requirement? Ie are client-a users allowed to see client-b documents?

If they are not allowed then you can use three different document libraries with different permissions.

I hope I understood your question, otherwise please elaborate.

/WW

Comment: so I would create a security group for each client and assign each user to their client->security group??

Comment: Yup, that sounds like the right way to do it! How many clients do you have?

Comment: as many as our sales team can get. right now only 6

Comment: Ok, then this should be no problem. I was thinking if you had a few hundreds then it could be a bit troublesome managing the groups and users

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Wictor is right.

My understanding is that the clients can only see their own company's documents, and in that case I would just create 3 different Document Libraries with their own security settings, as Wictor suggested.